# Convert curl command with form files into python requests

Tags: python, elasticsearch, curl, python-requests

I have the following curl command:

```
curl -X POST "_my_username_:_my_password_@10.2.25.209:5601/api/saved_objects/_import" -H "kbn-xsrf: true" --form file=@V:kibana\IndexPatterns\events.ndjson
```

Which works perfectly (import index pattern into elasticsearch), but I'm trying to convert it to Python requests. I tried several ways, including the following:

```
files = {'file': '@' + args.kibana_index_pattern_path}
res = requests.post("http://{0}:{1}@{2}:5601/api/saved_objects/_import".format(args.elastic_username, args.elastic_password, args.kibana_host),
                    headers={'kbn-xsrf': 'true'}, data=files)


files = {'file': '@' + args.kibana_index_pattern_path}
res = requests.post("http://{0}:{1}@{2}:5601/api/saved_objects/_import".format(args.elastic_username, args.elastic_password, args.kibana_host),
                    headers={'kbn-xsrf': 'true', 'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}, files=files)
```

With different combinations of with or without the `@`, files as a single string instead of dictionary, ect. I keep getting errors on bad requests and invalid content types (for example: {'message': 'Unsupported Media Type', 'error': 'Unsupported Media Type', 'statusCode': 415}).

Note that there are some tools to convert curl to requests, but all the ones I tried don't recognize the files param, either ignoring it or throwing exception. The command itself, however, works.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you share the errors you’re getting?

Comment: One approach is to review the requests that are generated by the tools.  Using `curl -v` will provde you with all the headers of the HTTP request.  Consider reviewing the debug information of the request module (somehow) and comparing it to the working curl request.  You can then concentrate your efforts on the missing (or different) HTTP headers.  If you don't know how to get debug info from `requests` (I don't yet) you may consider doing a packet capture to review the HTTP headers.

Comment: @AMC got many errors depending on variations I tried, but most common one is: {'message': 'Unsupported Media Type', 'error': 'Unsupported Media Type', 'statusCode': 415}

Comment: @RonenNess Did the solution by Victor S work?

Comment: @AMC unfortunately it did not work. The authentication is OK the problem is with the added file for some reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

username = '_my_username_'
password = '_my_password_'
headers = {'kbn-xsrf': 'true'}
upload_url = "http://10.2.25.209:5601/api/saved_objects/_import"
files = {'file': open('V:\algotec\analytics\install\Kibana\IndexPatterns\events.ndjson', 'rb')}

r = requests.post(upload_url, headers=headers, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password), files=files)
print(r.status_code)
```

If you receive a bad request with this error

> error: 'Bad Request', message: 'Request must contain a kbn-xsrf
>   header.'

Modify the header information as per the below and re-try.

```
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-ndjson',
  'kbn-xsrf': 'anything',
  'Accept': 'application/x-ndjson'
}
```

Comment: Hi Victor, unfortunately it didn't work, ES expects a string file and not binary. PS. the authentication is OK the problem is with the added file for some reason.

Comment: @RonenNess what's the response code your getting and message?

Comment: {'message': 'Unsupported Media Type', 'error': 'Unsupported Media Type', 'statusCode': 415}). About auth - we use other apis the same way and auth works there, this is the only api that gives us problems, possible because the files. Thanks

Comment: @RonenNess are you using ES 6.0?

Comment: @RonenNess the problem is the Content-type:  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ml-post-data.html#ml-post-data-desc . I have updated the headers to include Newline delimited JSON (NDJSON), which is what is being sent. If it fails again, my suggestion would be to remove 'Accept', then 'kbn-xsrf' until your left with Content-Type. A matter of trial and error until.

Comment: Hi @Victor S, it got a little postponed by higher priority stuff so I haven't tried it yet, I will keep you updated when I get back to this. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi sorry for the waiting, the error is still the same unfortunately.